# Transform/resize image for label printer using Gimp

Tags: gimp, images, image-quality

Starting from an image like this one, how do I resize and transform it into something a label printer can use? That means a black and white bmp about 1/3 of this size.

The best result I have so far are with an [online converter](http://www.online-convert.com/) but this image became a smudge.

[image: Chemical corrosion warning]

I use 2" x 4" autoadhesive labels, and I need to reduce images to 1/2" or smaller.

This is on a PC with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, the image needs to be cleaned.

In **GIMP** you can use the [Select By Color](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html) tool with a threshold of e.g. 30 and select the background:

[image: select by color]

Delete the selection with *del* key and un-select with *Shift-Ctrl-A*:

[image: cleaned image]

[Scale](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-scale.html) the image to the desired size using a proper interpolation algorithm:

[image: scale_image]

Note that now the drawing is very little:

[image: scaled_image]

In order to obtain a black and white image you could apply the [Threshold](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-threshold.html) tool (in *Colors* menu), but you can loose the red border or the detail of the image:

[image: threshold 1] [image: threshold 2]

Perhaps is better [Desaturate](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-desaturate.html) (in *Colors* menu) the image before to apply the threshold:

[image: desaturate]

Now the image is a little better:

[image: threshold 3]

Before exporting the image, you must transform it in a black and white one changing the mode to [indexed](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-convert-indexed.html) (*Image* menu):

[image: indexed mode]

Now you can [export](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-images-out.html) it to BMP.

Please note that the result of the print may depend on printer settings and printer driver. For certain kinds of printers you can send directly a bigger (and more resolute) image, and they will adapt it to the label format.